# Install Os on remote server

Tags: centos6, remote-access

I just purchased vps. As per my requirement, I need `Centos 6` but they are providing `Centos 7`. So, is there any way by which I can install `Centos 6` on remote server ?

Comment: Have your supplier replace the VPS with one with the correct OS image.

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR in your situation it will be so much easier to just get a CentOS 6 VPS, you should do that rather than atempt to reinstall.

This only works if you have access to reinstall the kernel so it wouldn't work with an OpenVZ or similar VPs type (or similar) or where the kernel is loaded externaly.

I have been able to use the CentOS [install from grub](https://wiki.centos.org/TipsAndTricks/InstallFromGRUB)<sup>*</sup> feature. Basically you

- Downoad the instalation kernel files to /boot.
- Update the grub configuration file to boot the installation kernel from above
- configure the installation kernel command line to

  - run vnc for an interactive install or to monitor progress
  - run an unattended install by configuring kickstart

When I had to do this I was using VMs to develop it for remote installing bare metal. I had full access to the VM host and the vm to reinstall it when I messed up but you clearly don't. If you don't have the ability to reinstall your VPS then support will I'm sure quickly get irritated with you.

<sup>*</sup>The instructions I linked rare for CentOS 5 but work the same for CentOS 6. They are broadly the same for CentOS 7 bu some of the kernel command line options are different so you will need to research them.